# JavaScript error only in Chrome, works fine in Safari?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-applications, iphone-web-app

I have the following code to set up a database and its tables on an iDevice, when a user starts a standalone web app. The code is working fine if it is used on the device with Safari but if it is opened in Chrome it throws the following error

```
Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11
```

Besides the error it also prevents other functions from working, again only in Chrome.
Here is the code, including the function to create the tables. I have added a comment in the code on the line that Chrome indicates the error.

```
//this sets up the DB name global variable and uses it to open the DB
        var dbName = 'CBNapp',
        db = openDatabase(dbName, '1.0', dbName, 65536);// chrome error = UncaughtError: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11 (anonymous function) line 43
//            db = openDatabase(dbName, '1.0' /*version*/, dbName, 65536 /*max size*/);
//opens the database when the document is loaded
$(document).ready(openCBNappDB);

function openCBNappDB(){
//this if statement checks to see if device supports offline storage
    if ( !window.openDatabase ) {
        $('add_note').innerHTML = "Browser does not support local storage."
        return;
    }
// create tables in the DB
    function dbTransaction(fn) {
       db.transaction(fn);
    }
    /*create 5 tables*/ //colums in tables are not correct as of apr 25 2012
    dbTransaction(
        function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE CBNapp_Usage (key INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, MemberID TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT "", NewKnife INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, True INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, Trivia INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, Movies INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, Jokes INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, Musings INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, Stories INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE CBNapp_Members (key INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, MemberID TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT "", CBNname TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT "", Community TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT "", BirthDay TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT "", BirthMonth TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT "", Gender TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT "Male", iOS TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT "", Device TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT "");');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE CBNapp_Scores (key INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, MemberID TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT "", GameName TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT "", TimesPlayed INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, HiScore INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 );');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE CBNapp_UserPrefs (key INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, MemberID TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT "", TextSize INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 14, AutoRetrieve INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 );');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE CBNapp_Errors (key INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, MemberID TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT "", code INTEGER NOT NULL, message TEXT NOT NULL );');
    }
);
}
```

If anyone could please suggest a specific solution to get this to work properly with Chrome and Safari it would be much appreciated.

I am sure I have made many other errors in the script as well. If anyone wishes to take the time to show me how I should improve it I would be very thankful for any ideas. I am VERY new at this and would ask for specific suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's hard to say for sure without knowing the HTML but I'm guessing chrome doesn't have a openDataBase method assigned to its window object and that branches to some bad JQuery:

```
$('add_note').innerHTML = "Browser does not support local storage."
```

'add_note' is meaningless. If add_note is a class it should be `'.add_note'` or `'#add_note'` if an ID.

Also, since it's JQuery, it's probably not going to have the innerHTML method. Quickest fix assuming an ID would probably be:

```
$('#add_note')[0].innerHTML = "Browser does not support local storage."
```

But that might bust if it's a form element like a text input.

Comment: Hello Erik, Thanks for the reply. I tried both suggestions and nothing seems to change. The other functions still do not work and the same error is displayed.